# how to select first rows distinct by a column name in a sub-query in sql-server?

Tags: sql-server

Actually I am building a Skype like tool wherein I have to show last 10 distinct users who have logged in my web application.
I have maintained a table in sql-server where there is one field called last_active_time. So, my requirement is to sort the table by last_active_time and show all the columns of last 10 distinct users.
There is another field called WWID which uniquely identifies a user.
I am able to find the distinct WWID but not able to select the all the columns of those rows.
I am using below query for finding the distinct wwid :

```
 select distinct(wwid) from(select top 100 * from dbo.rvpvisitors where last_active_time!='' order by last_active_time DESC) as newView;
```

But how do I find those distinct rows. I want to show how much time they are away fromm web apps using the diff between curr time and last active time.
I am new to sql, may be the question is naive, but struggling to get it right.

Comment: please comment if the question is not clear.

Comment: the primary key of the table is id

Comment: is last_active_time a date or datetime column? the desired output is just made of the columns wwid and last_active_time ?

Comment: last_active_time is string only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using proper data types for your columns you won't need a subquery to get that result, the following query should do the trick

```
SELECT TOP 10
     [wwid]
    ,MAX([last_active_time]) AS [last_active_time]
FROM [dbo].[rvpvisitors]
WHERE 
    [last_active_time] != ''
GROUP BY 
    [wwid]
ORDER BY 
    [last_active_time] DESC
```

If the column [last_active_time] is of type varchar/nvarchar (which probably is the case since you check for empty strings in the WHERE statement) you might need to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to treat it as an actual date, and be able to use function like MIN/MAX on it.

In general I would suggest you to use proper data types for your column, if you have dates or timestamps data use the "date" or "datetime2" data types

**Edit**:
The query aggregates the data based on the column [wwid], and for each returns the maximum [last_active_time].
The result is then sorted and filtered.

In order to add more columns "as-is" (without aggregating them) just add them in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` sections. 
If you need more aggregated columns add them in the `SELECT` with the appropriate aggregation function (MIN/MAX/SUM/etc)

- I suggest you have a look at `GROUP BY` on [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- To know more about the "execution order" of the instruction you can have a look [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-logical-query-processing)

Comment: It is working like charm. Thanks a lot. Please care to explain sir as I am not able to understand the query.

Comment: Also how do I get the all columns of those rows . Please advise.

Comment: I've edited the answer to briefly explain what you asked, I hope it suffices. If you are a newbie of SQL I suggest you have a look at W3 school, they have quick and well-made examples and exercises

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problem like this by rank ordering the results by a key and finding the last x of those items, this removes duplicates while preserving the key order.

```
;
WITH RankOrdered AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        wwidRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wwid ORDER BY last_active_time DESC )
    FROM 
        dbo.rvpvisitors 
    where 
        last_active_time!='' 
)

SELECT TOP(10) * FROM RankOrdered WHERE wwidRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, below query will give the desired output.

You can have conditions according to your need.

select top 10 distinct wwid from dbo.rvpvisitors order by last_active_time desc